# Java SAX и одиночные теги

Tags: java, sax

Необходимо написать парсер с использованием библиотеки SAX. Как реализовать запись одиночных самозакрывающихся тегов, таких как

```
<property name="sessionFactory"/>
```

Используя 'getStartElement()', я получаю.

```
<property name="sessionFactory"></property>
```

Это, вообще, возможно отличить средствами этой бибилиотки парные и непраные теги?

Comment: А вам оно нужно? Разница пустого и самозакрывающегося тега исключительно в написании.

Comment: Если эта возможность существует, то ее обязательно надо использовать. Я не смогла найти информацию, поэтому решила спросить у более осведомленных людей.

Comment: Если использовать `SAX` без расширений, то вы данную ситуацию не обнаружите.